# center a div in center of screen with a background image using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a function that adds centering ability to jquery.
it works find when applied to a div with the text.
but when the background is set it doesn't work. 
what am I doing wrong?

here is a fiddle demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/k3ugj74e/

```
<div id='target'></div>

$.fn.center = function() {
    this.css("position", "absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;                
}

var i ='https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/googles-18th-birthday-5661535679545344-hp.gif'

var backgroundimage = "url('" + i + "') no-repeat";

//this doesn't
$("#target").parent().css('background', backgroundimage);

//this works
//$("#target").text('hi');

$("#target").center(true);
```

Comment: If you want to centre a background image you should give it a `background-position`. Use the keyword `center` for both the x and y axis. EG: the shorthand form would be `background:url("imagePath") center center no-repeat;` (See: http://jsfiddle.net/k3ugj74e/5/)

Comment: @moob thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code always works for me:

```
$('#yourimage').css({'top':'50%','left':'50%','margin':'-'+($('#yourimage').height() / 2)+'px 0 0 -'+($('#yourimage').width() / 2)+'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

a background image does not automatically give your div a width and height, you have to set that manually for your center function to work.

also, you set the background of the div´s parent, not of the div itself, and after that you´re trying center the empty div, which obviously has no visible effect